# Show filename and line number in grep output

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to search my rails directory using grep. I am looking for a specific word and I want to grep to print out the file name and line number.

Is there a grep flag that will do this for me? I have been trying to use a combination of `-n` and `-l` but these are either printing out the file names with no numbers or just dumping out a lot of text to the terminal which can't be easily read.

ex:

```
  grep -ln "search" *
```

Do I need to pipe it to awk?

Comment: Related: [Display filename before matching line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15432156/6862601).

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I think `-l` is too restrictive as it suppresses the output of `-n`. I would suggest `-H` (`--with-filename`): Print the filename for each match.

```bash
grep -Hn "search" *
```

If that gives too much output, try `-o` to only print the part that matches.

```bash
grep -nHo "search" *
```

Comment: This answer worked out also for me. I was in need of searching recursively and used this example command:
grep -Hnor "localhost" . 
This listet up all matches with file name and line number, short and concise.

Comment: This also displays the result and not just the filename and line number

Answer (score 34):

```
grep -rin searchstring * | cut -d: -f1-2
```

This would say, search recursively (for the string `searchstring` in this example), ignoring case, and display line numbers.  The output from that grep will look something like:

```
/path/to/result/file.name:100: Line in file where 'searchstring' is found.
```

Next we pipe that result to the cut command using colon `:` as our field delimiter and displaying fields 1 through 2.

When I don't need the line numbers I often use `-f1` (just the filename and path), and then pipe the output to `uniq`, so that I only see each filename once:

```
grep -ir searchstring * | cut -d: -f1 | uniq
```

Comment: I feel this best answers the original question. File names and line numbers only.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you have absolute path names of Windows like `C:\Users\me\git\` as it already contains one colon.

Answer (score 29):

I like using:

`grep -niro 'searchstring' <path>`

But that's just because I always forget the other ways and I can't forget **Robert de `grep -` niro** for some reason :)

Comment: Never thought I'd get upvotes for the above. Just a fun share. Thanks! (But it really works -- at least on MacOS)

Comment: Love your way of remembering this!

Answer (score 8):

The comment from @ToreAurstad can be spelled `grep -Horn 'search' ./`, which is easier to remember.

`grep -HEroine 'search' ./` could also work ;)

For the curious:

```
$ grep --help | grep -Ee '-[HEroine],'
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERNS are extended regular expressions
  -e, --regexp=PATTERNS     use PATTERNS for matching
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
  -H, --with-filename       print file name with output lines
  -o, --only-matching       show only nonempty parts of lines that match
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I used the upvoted answer to search a tree to find the fortran files containing a string:

```
find . -name "*.f" -exec grep -nHo the_string {} \;
```

Without the nHo, you learn only that some file, somewhere, matches the string.