# Display filename before matching line

Tags: unix, grep

How can I get `grep` to display the filename before the matching lines in its output?

Answer (score 517, accepted):

Try this little trick to coax `grep` into thinking it is dealing with multiple files, so that it displays the filename:

```
grep 'pattern' file /dev/null
```

To also get the line number:

```
grep -n 'pattern' file /dev/null
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you please tell me whats the significance of adding `/dev/null` in this command?

Comment: If `grep` is supplied with multiple file names, it will automatically display the file names before the match, but it will leave the file name out in case of a single input file. By using `/dev/null` as an extra input file `grep` "thinks" it dealing with multiple files, but /dev/null is of course empty, so it will not show up in the match list..

Comment: using /dev/null is a clever trick, but I think the suggestion below of the -H flag is a better answer.

Comment: OK, but the `-H` option for grep is not part of POSIX, and the OS used is Solaris 10, where neither the standard grep, nor the POSIX compliant version of grep have the `-H` option.

Comment: Actually with using -n you don't need the /dev/null

Comment: @iptizer: Yes you do. Also with -n grep leaves out the filename when used with a single file

Comment: That's important if you are using grep with find, like `find . -name foo -exec grep pattern {} \;` - assuming plenty of files named `foo` in your subdirectory, `find` still hands `grep` a single file to operate on at a time.  The `/dev/null` trick seems to work in all linux/osx flavors that I've tried, so kudos!  Note I think that `-H` is cleaner, but as mentioned below, it might not be supported with _your_ version of `grep`.

Comment: Also in most cases should be possible to simply use `+` instead of `\;` in order to achieve the same "multiple files grep" without any /dev/null workarounds.

Comment: @RAM237: True, but even then there may be a cases where find only returns one file.

Comment: I found my problem was the filename wasn't showing because I was using grep against `/dev/filename*`, where I suppose it's consider a blob, not a directory?

Answer (score 366):

If you have the options `-H` and `-n` available (`man grep` is your friend):

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
foobar

$ grep -H foo file
file:foo
file:foobar

$ grep -Hn foo file
file:1:foo
file:3:foobar
```

Options:

> -H, --with-filename
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is
>   more than one  file  to
>                 search.
>
> -n, --line-number
>
> Prefix each line of output with the 1-based  line  number  within  its
>   input  file.   (-n  is
>                 specified by POSIX.)

`-H` is a GNU extension, but `-n` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Comment: No, `-H` is not supported here.

Comment: Supported but it always gives grep: file: No such file or directory

Comment: works on ubuntu -H and -n. Probably with all newer versions of *nix

Comment: I have struggled with that for years without evening thinking there were these options!

Answer (score 62):

No trick necessary.

```
grep --with-filename 'pattern' file
```

With line numbers:

```
grep -n --with-filename 'pattern' file
```

Comment: @codeforester I don't know of any other `grep`s, so I don't know.

Comment: Cool ! this worked for linux. if you use mac, can install coreutils with brew. And remember add PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" to yours .bashrc

Comment: This (also) worked in [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) (1.0.17, I think).

Comment: It works for me with the built-in Mac grep (2.5.1-FreeBSD). But to use the alternative grep from Homebrew, another way is to run `brew install grep` and then just use `ggrep`. No need to modify PATH.

Answer (score 7):

How about this, which I managed to achieve thanks, in part, to this post.

You want to find several files, lets say logs with different names but a pattern (e.g. `filename=logfile.DATE`), inside several directories with a pattern (e.g. `/logsapp1, /logsapp2`).
Each file has a pattern you want to grep (e.g. `"init time"`), and you want to have the `"init time"` of each file, but knowing which file it belongs to.

```
find ./logsapp* -name logfile* | xargs -I{} grep "init time" {} \dev\null | tee outputfilename.txt
```

Then the `outputfilename.txt` would be something like

```
./logsapp1/logfile.22102015: init time: 10ms
./logsapp1/logfile.21102015: init time: 15ms
./logsapp2/logfile.21102015: init time: 17ms
./logsapp2/logfile.22102015: init time: 11ms
```

In general

```
find ./path_pattern/to_files* -name filename_pattern* | xargs -I{} grep "grep_pattern" {} \dev\null | tee outfilename.txt
```

Explanation:

`find` command will search the filenames based in the pattern

then, pipe `xargs -I{}` will redirect the `find` output to the `{}`

which will be the input for `grep ""pattern" {}`

Then the trick to make `grep` display the filenames `\dev\null`

and finally, write the output in file with `tee outputfile.txt`

This worked for me in `grep` version 9.0.5 build 1989.

Comment: Or just using find `find ./path_pattern/to_files -type f -name "files*.log" -exec grep -Hn pattern {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification from a previous solution.  My example looks for stderr redirection in bash scripts:
`grep '2>' $(find . -name "*.bash")`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
grep -r pattern files
```

it will display filename first, then the string.

Answer (score -7):

```
grep 'search this' *.txt
```

worked for me to search through all .txt files (enter your own search value, of course).