# Solaris: find files not containing a string (alternative to grep -L)

Tags: bash, unix, grep, solaris

I want to search files that does **not** contain a specific string.

I used `-lv` but this was a huge mistake because it was returning all the files that contain any line not containing my string.

I knew what I need exactly is `grep -L`, however, Solaris `grep` does not implement this feature.

What is the alternative, if any?

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit `grep -c` and do the following (thanks @Scrutinizer for the `/dev/null` hint):

```
grep -c foo /dev/null * 2>/dev/null | awk -F: 'NR>1&&!$2{print $1}'
```

This will unfortunately also print directories (if `*` expands to any) which might not be desired in which case a simple loop, albeit slower, might be your best bet:

```
for file in *; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    grep -q foo "${file}" 2>/dev/null || echo "${file}"
done
```

However, if you have `GNU awk 4` on your system you can do:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{f=0} /foo/{f=1} ENDFILE{if(!f)print FILENAME}' *
```

Comment: Nice approach. There would be a problem if the result is a single file, since then there is no filename with a colon in the output. You could use `/dev/null` similar to like I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432156/display-filename-and-match-in-grep/15432718#15432718 and use it as the first argument and print `NR>1` in `awk`

Comment: @Scrutinizer Thanks for your input, very valid point! I adapted my answer but realized that this will also print directories which is certainly not desired :(

Answer (score 0):

after using `grep -c` u can use `grep` again to find your desired filenames:

```
grep -c 'pattern' *  | grep  ':0$'
```

and to see just filnames :

```
grep -c 'pattern' *  | grep  ':0$' | cut -d":" -f1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '!/not this/' file
```

To do multiple not:

```
awk '!/jan|feb|mars/' file
```

Comment: This will return all lines from `file` that do not contain `not this` which is certainly not what OP wants.