# How to get file name of the linux awk and find results

Tags: linux, bash, awk

i have this linux command using pipes which find files in directyrids and grep and awk on the results the 
 command working just fine , what im missing is  the bility to get the file name of the results so i could know what is the source file of the result .

```
 $ find . -name "*.log" | xargs grep -i TypeOf | grep -v 'Error=APP1' | awk '{split($0,a,"Name="); print a[2]}' | sort -h
```

how do i add to this command something to pring the file names

Comment: Can you show us some examples of where you are applying this? for us to test it on? Provide a Minimal, Verifiable and testable input and an expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display filename and match in grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432156/display-filename-and-match-in-grep)

Comment: you may need  grep -Hi TypeOf

Comment: We may not know if you can use any flags in `grep`, unless show us some output at end of each pipe-line (some sample data) to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `awk` program. You discard all fields except the second, including the file name, which should be first. You probably need to use something like:

```
awk -F: '{split($0,a,"Name="); print $1, a[2]}'
```

Comment: Thanks allot it worked , do you know how to add line number of result?

Comment: In order to get the line number, you need to use the option `-n` when calling `grep` for the __first__ time. And then your `awk` action becomes `'{split($0,a,"Name="); print $1, $2, a[2]}'`.

Comment: No, that's just adding to the mess. The right approach is to just not add a bunch of leading greps and pipes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add much but you do need to remove several things. You never need grep when you're using awk and `split()` is what awk does by default so your existing command line should just be:

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs awk -F"Name=' 'tolower($0)~/typeof/ && !/Error=APP1/ {print $2}' | sort -h
```

and then to print the file name and line number just add them to the print statement:

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs awk -F'Name=' 'tolower($0)~/typeof/ && !/Error=APP1/ {print FILENAME, FNR, $2}' | sort -h
```