# How can I grep through multiple files and print any file names that have the string present?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to know which files in a folder contain a certain string. There are many answers on here showing how to grep through many files. However, is there a way to print out the file names that have the string present?

I want to use something like:

```
grep -E '275322' *.txt
```

Can I use echo to print the file currently being looked at if the string is present?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432156/display-filename-before-matching-line will help?

Comment: `grep -H .....`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/57321/411978

Comment: Note that `-H` is implied by default when there are multiple files (which will depend on your glob's expansion)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you *only* want the filenames?

```
grep -l '275322' *
```

Check the [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) -

```
  -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```