# BASH : Search a file for specific string & upon a match read the logfile associated with the string

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a file with below entries

```
Command     : apply
Log File    : /u01/test/123.log

Command     : list
Log File    : /u01/test/456.log

Command     : rollback
Log File    : /u01/test/123.log
```

My aim is to look for apply/rollback commands & then look in the Logfiles for a particular string "Make failed"
Was looking at awk range patterns,but confused...Please advise

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: also, it would be beneficial to get sample input that complies with all possible requirements IE you said you're looking for the string "Make failed." Finally, something showing expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to use [multi-line record processing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) instead of range patterns.

If you have a file called `commands-and-logs.txt` with the following contents (I prepended `/tmp/` to your example contents so that I could create the files to test it out):

```
Command     : apply
Log File    : /tmp/u01/test/123.log

Command     : list
Log File    : /tmp/u01/test/456.log

Command     : rollback
Log File    : /tmp/u01/test/123.log
```

you could run:

`awk -v RS="" -v FS="[:\n]" '$2 ~ /apply|rollback/ {print $4}' commands-and-logs.txt | sort -u | xargs grep -n "Make failed" /dev/null`.

For me, with `/tmp/u01/test/123.log` containing:

```
Line with Make failed 1
Line without...
Line without...
Line with Make failed 2
Line with Make failed 3
Line without...
```

and `/tmp/u01/test/456.log` containing:

```
Line without anything interesting...
Line with Make failed 4
Line with Make failed 5
Line without...
Line without...
```

the command I provided prints:

```
/tmp/u01/test/123.log:1:Line with Make failed 1
/tmp/u01/test/123.log:4:Line with Make failed 2
/tmp/u01/test/123.log:5:Line with Make failed 3
```

Breaking this down:

1. Awk's `-v` option means "set this variable within Awk."
2. `RS` and `FS` mean set the record and field separators.
3. [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) (linked above) has info on how to set `RS` to the special value `""` to use multi-line records.
4. [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html#Regexp-Field-Splitting) has info on setting `FS` to a regular expression. In this case it makes sense to have the field separator be the regex `[:\n]` meaning "either colon or newline." Try `awk -v RS="" -v FS="[:\n]" '{printf("$1: %s, $2: %s, $3: %s, $4: %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' commands-and-logs.txt` to get a sense of how the fields get split.
5. The [regex pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Patterns.html#Regexp-Patterns) `$2 ~ /apply|rollback/` means "only show me entries where *Command* is 'apply' or 'rollback.'"
6. `print $4` prints the 4th field (the Log File name).
7. I'm piping into `sort -u` so I don't search files multiple times.
8. `xargs grep` searches the matched Log Files. I'm appending `/dev/null` to the argument list based on [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432156/display-filename-before-matching-line) for always listing the file name next to the matched lines.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sry for the delay.Your help is truly appreciated